# What distribution formula do I need for this please?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've just tripped over Hypergeometric Distribution and have implemented the calculator in [this Google Sheets doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rwTOzWjmYvhMw_U4dNx_nVweYs6ej0aHgI7Hq-HvuKw/edit#gid=1831199487) for a bit of rudimentary calculations on the fly.

I wanted to create a chart that plotted the probability of draw 4 cards (x) of a specific type from a deck of 30 if said deck contained 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 copies of x cards.  I thought this fit perfectly into Hypergeometric Distribution, but then I realised that the charts were going DOWN.  I'm assuming that it is calculating the chance of EXACTLY 4 successes - whereas I would like to determine the probability of AT LEAST 4 successes.

Binomial distribution sure doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Watch out, your Google Sheet is writable :-)

Comment: Yeah I made it editable.  I usually post in the Google Sheets department of Stack Overflow and they require sheets be editable.  This one just a copy of my original sheet so anyone can mess around with it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the right distribution; you just need to use the cumulative distribution function instead of the probability mass function. Unfortunately [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) gives this in the form of a hypergeometric series, so there apparently isn’t a closed form for it.

From what I can gather from the net, Excel seems to have cumulative distribution functions (see [here](http://www.mathwave.com/articles/probability-distributions-excel.html)), but Google Sheets apparently doesn’t (only for the normal distribution). So you might just have to add up the values yourself.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply!  Would it simply be a matter of adding up every probability outcome of 4 cards and above?  Such as if there are 8 x cards in the deck then the probability of drawing 4 after y turns is the Hypergeometric Distribution of exactly 4, plus exactly 5, plus exactly 6......etc to 8?  Draws beyond 4 are redundant for the actual game per se.

Comment: @AaronIrvine: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you!  I've updated the sheet accordingly.  The chart looks a lot more like a cumulative distribution chart now - not sure if it's correct but I followed your instruction

Comment: @AaronIrvine: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help @joriki!!